# Why is math evaluation as var=$((expresison)) slower than ((var=expression)) in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

Why if I try, for example, `x2=$((x+2))` it is slower than `((x2=x+2))`?

If I try to run it millions of times in a loop to get a sample, like this:

```
~ %  time ( for ((i=0;i<=6553600;i++)); do i2=$((i+2)); done)
9.46s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 9.472 total
```

it will always be about 40~60% slower than doing the exact same thing, but setting the variable inside the parenthesis:

```
~ % time ( for ((i=0;i<=6553600;i++)); do ((i2=i+2)); done)
6.59s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 6.601 total
```

I presumed the first option would fork off a subshell to do the operation, but when I tried to look on `top`, with forest view and showing execution threads, I couldn't spot anything being forked from there, other than the subshell I explicitly declared, nor I could see anything with `forkstat`. So what is the difference between the two ways? Does `var=$((expression))` first evaluates the expression, then stores it in a temporary variable, and finally sets the declared variable, while `((var=expression))` evaluates the expression and sets the variable directly?

Comment: `((var=expression))` does everything inside an arithmetic context; `var=$((expression))` runs one command inside an arithmetic context, and another outside it. However, if this implementation artifact matters in any practical way (a word intentionally chosen given SO's exclusive focus on *practical*, answerable questions), I submit that you're using the wrong language for your problem at hand.